# Python Telegram Bot Markdown symbol '[' or ']'

Tags: python, markdown, telegram

how to get in send_message symbol '[' and ']' if I use parse_mode = 'Markdown'? Now it replaces the characters with a space

Answer (score 2):

In markdown, special characters can be escaped with a backslash

```
\[\]
```

Answer (score 1):

The list of characters you must escape is `` ('_', '*', '[', ']', '(', ')', '~', '`', '>', '#', '+', '-', '=', '|', '{', '}', '.', '!') ``

To add a specific for Telegram escaping you can just use PlainText from [telegram-text](https://github.com/SKY-ALIN/telegram-text):

```
from telegram_text import PlainText

element = PlainText("[text to escape]")
escaped_text = element.to_markdown()
escaped_text
'\\[text to escape\\]'
```